# CouchDB view javascript only supports a subset of JS features?

Tags: javascript, regex, nosql, couchdb

I am trying to write a few map functions to create views in a CouchDB database. Futon kept telling me that the script I wrote is not a valid function - despise that I used mostly standard JS features. After some debugging, I found that if I use standard `string.match(//)`, `string.replace(//,'')`, `array.filter()`, `array.map()` calls, or lambda functions `((x) => x * 2)`, it will fail to save the document.

This gives me the feeling that couchdb only supports a subset of JS, but could not find a document on what JS features are not supported.

Can someone let me know if such document exist? why couchjs does not support standard JS functions?

my server has couchdb v3.3.2.

Comment: Check out [v3 release notes](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/whatsnew/3.0.html). Maybe this phrase applies to your setup? *"It is unlikely we will backport SM 60 packages to older versions of Debian, CentOS, RedHat, or Ubuntu."*

Comment: you are correct. the current server runs on Ubuntu 18.04. I will try setting up another server on 22.04 and see if this can be fixed.